# My Partial view is not loading from the correct file location inside my area

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using Areas and I am loading a partial view that is setup like the following:

```
/Areas/Users/Controllers/UserController.cs

public ActionResult Index()
{

    return View("Index", model);
}
```

Now inside the Index.cshtml I load the partial view like this:

```
 @{
        Html.RenderPartial("_User", Model.UserPartialViewModal);
    }
```

The partial view is at:

```
/Areas/Users/Views/User/_User.cshtml
```

When the user pages the results, it then makes a jQuery POST ajax request and loads data from the GetUserPartialView action.

```
public ActionResult GetUserPartialView(...)
{

    return View("_User", model);
}
```

Now the problem is, the above action GetUserPartialView doesn't load the partial from the path /Areas/Users/Views/User/_User.cshtml.
I kept on getting errors saying it was not able to locate the view to load.

I ended up duplicating the _User.cshtml partial view and I had to place it at the root:

```
/Views/User/_User.cshtml
```

What is the reason the partial view is not laoding correctly?  Can i be more explicit on the location of the view?

**Update**
Area registration code:

```
public class UserAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
    {
        public override string AreaName 
        {
            get 
            {
                return "User";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "User_default",
                "User/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any [AreaRegistration](http://dotnetmentors.com/mvc/how-to-use-areas-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx) code that you have not included?

Comment: Sounds like you need to set view engine to find views (and partial views) inside `/Areas/Users/Views/User` path. Did you already tried to set custom view engine to search partial views inside area?

Comment: @HoomanBahreini updated with my area registration

Comment: Do you make a call to: `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();` in Application_Start? This should be the first line in Application_Start.

Comment: @HoomanBahreini Yes I have that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Html.Partial

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Users/_User.cshtml", Model.UserPartialViewModal)
```

Comment: `RenderPartial` and `Partial` parameters are no different, that isn't the issue.  Changing the location as you have may fix the issue, but isn't the underlying problem.

Answer (score 0):

> My Partial view is not loading from the correct file location inside my area

You're route does not denote it's area so the view engine cannot find the view.  Update your RouteMap:

```
context.MapRoute(
  "User_default",
  "User/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
  ).DataTokens["area"] = AreaName;
```

Comment: What is ```public override string AreaName ``` for then? (see my code above)